# Recording Software for multiple input devices

Tags: sound, multimedia

Does anyone know of any software that will allow me to record from multiple sound cards at once?

I tried Audacity but they seem to only support one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/27416/9598) but the previous one refers to a command line needs. Nevertheless, [my previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27448/9598) is also useful for your case, placed here for your convenience:

> I am not familiar to command line recording but in your case a GUI may
>   help.
>
> I think Ardour can help you with this tasks but yes, you will be in
>   the need to use JACK in order to tell Ardour where exactly to gather
>   audio inputs. Ardour will be able to handle per input track generation
>   the same as other features.
>
> I am personally not using Ardour, I use Audacity which is also an
>   audio multi-track editor/recorder and may be you can use it to extract
>   your multi-track wav into single wav files.
>
> My suggestion would be you to give a chance to Ubuntu Studio, which is
>   a distribution that features the majority of the tools needed to do
>   multi-media tasks and is using JACK as the main audio engine.
>
> You can reach Ubuntu Studio and download an iso in order to burn a
>   CD/DVD from the next link.
>
> http://ubuntustudio.org/
>
> After burnt, simply perform a Live Session in order to check if
>   Ardour, Audacity and JACK fits what you need. This way you won't harm
>   your current OS installation.
>
> I would appreciate a lot if you inform about your results and I am
>   sorry because of I can't help you further at this time because of I am
>   using a version of Ubuntu other than Studio.
>
> Good Luck!
>
> Screenshots of Ardour in action are placed here for your convenience:
>
> *Here is Ardour's Session Control (seen at startup)*
>
> [image]
>
> *Here is Ardour GUI*
>
> [image]

Give Ardour a chance and please inform if you succeeded.

Good luck!

Comment: I did end up figuring it out by using Jack2 and Ardour. I used the alsa_in command on each of my USB audio cards. Once I did that I was able to connect the devices to audio tracks in Ardour using the Track Bus Inspector.

Comment: First of all: nice to know you found a solution. It would be interesting if you share your procedure in an answer over here in order to have it for future reference. And I notice in your comment that you refer to USB audio cards, information that could be useful if you add it in your question in order to receive the proper support. Well done! And good luck!